# Create a DBI bind param surrounded by " and not '

Tags: perl, dbi

I am using MySQL to access SphinxQL, so not a normal mysql setup. I am trying to safely insert text into a bind parameter into my query (so I can safely insert anywhere into the string).

I am currently using DBI, and it all works fine, but feels clunky what I have to do.

The SphinxQL needs a string like

`SELECT * FROM someindex WHERE MATCH ('@somefield "sometext"')`

It seems to insist on the outer quotes being `'` and not `"`

Currently if I do a normal `?` or a `$h->quote($var)` it returns it single quoted. So always is `'some string'` and clashes with the type of quote.

I can get it working by

```
my $safe_query = $dbh->quote($query);
$safe_query =~ s/^'/"/;
$safe_query =~ s/'$/"/;
```

Then I can just insert it into the string (hopefully safely ? this currently "works" at least in terms of getting the results)

Naturally, this feels a bit clunky. Is there any way for either DBI->quote() to return a param surrounded by `"` ? Or call whatever DBI does under the hood to make sure a string is full escaped etc correctly to be inserted into a DB ?

Digging through DBI.pm I can see some code referencing things like `LITERAL_PREFIX` but get stuck around there, to see if there's an obvious workaround

Comment: *It seems to insist on the outer quotes being ' and not "* In normal SQL, single quotes are used for strings and double quotes to quote identifiers like column and table names where needed. (I know at one point MySQL used double quotes for strings in a non-standard "extension"; I have no idea if it still allows that)

Comment: Just bind a perl value holding the `@somefield "sometext"` to a parameter in the query?

Comment: Interesting, this was a simplified example of a more complex set, but actually it seems to work passing in the whole thing and calling quote() on it. Thanks, happy to accept that as an answer.